# Password protect PDF documents on the fly without compromising the password

Tags: pdf, encryption

I'm looking for a way to password protect PDF files on the fly without having to store the user's password in plaintext.

What I would like to do is to generate the user and owner keys according to the PDF specification and use those to encrypt the document's strings and streams. Is there a library out there that supports this functionality?

-- edit --

Just to clarify, what I want to do is allow the user to enter their password into the system once, then any time after that to be able to encrypt a PDF file with the key generated from that password. Most PDF libraries require the password to be passed in plaintext, what I want is an encryption function that takes the "public" key.

Comment: What could make you *having to store the user's password in plaintext?*

Comment: @mkl The command-line tool I'm using (qpdf) only provides options for plaintext passwords.

Comment: At some step during encryption your passwords are in plain text somewhere, even if only in memory. If that's ok for you, any decent general purpose PDF library will do. Are there any restrictions concerning the runtime environment or the licensing details of the lib?

Comment: @mkl see my edit for clarification.

Comment: Are you sure you are not mixing two concepts there? PDF knows both password based (symmetric) and certificate based (asymmetric) encryption, and your use of the word *password* points to the former mode while your use of *public key* points to the latter one.

Comment: @mkl I used _public key_ because I can't think of a better term. The password isn't stored in the file, and from poking around in qpdf source code it appears not to be needed for encryption if V>=5. What is stored in the file is an encryption key generated from the user and owner passwords and a few other parameters. It is that "public" encryption key that I want to use.

Answer (score 0):

http://itextpdf.com/ has open source Java and C# PDF libraries that include encryption.

Comment: Thanks. I took a look at the Java source. It can probably be modified to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Virtually every PDF library supports PDF encryption.

The user and owner passwords are stored in the encrypted PDF in exactly the same way by each library. This is a requisite because it's defined by the spec.

So in terms of libraries the differences you are going to find are going to be related to the encryption schemes supported rather than the actual storage of the passwords.

Most will support the old basic forms. Few support AES 256 bit encryption. It just depends what is important to you.

I work on the ABCpdf .NET software component so my replies may feature concepts based around ABCpdf. It's just what I know. :-)"

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say virtually every PDF library supports it. For instance, I was surprised to see that two of the major PDF libraries in Perl (CAM::PDF, and PDF::API2) don't support what the OP is trying to do, namely encrypting an unencrypted PDF created by another program. If you take a look at the PDF spec, its apparent why, definitely not trivial to add to a library.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the answer in the qpdf source.

line 999 of libqpdf/qpdfencryption.cc:

```
if (V < 5)
{
    // For V < 5, the user password is encrypted with the owner
    // password, and the user password is always used for
    // computing the encryption key.
    this->encryption_key = compute_encryption_key(
        this->user_password, data);
}
else
{
    // For V >= 5, either password can be used independently to
    // compute the encryption key, and neither password can be
    // used to recover the other.
    bool perms_valid;
    this->encryption_key = recover_encryption_key_with_password(
        this->provided_password, data, perms_valid);
    if (! perms_valid)
    {
        warn(QPDFExc(qpdf_e_damaged_pdf, this->file->getName(),
                     "encryption dictionary", this->file->getLastOffset(),
                     "/Perms field in encryption dictionary"
                     " doesn't match expected value"));
    }
}
```

Either way, a password is required to compute the encryption key. I suspect that the computed encryption key would be susceptible to reverse-engineering to recover the password, so storing that is also a bad idea.

The alternatives I can think of are:

1. Require the user to re-enter their password each time they download a file.
2. Have a less secure secondary password for each user - only used to encrypt PDF files. Ensure that it is different from the user's primary password.

I'm beginning to think that protecting PDF files with the user's primary password will probably create a security vulnerability. I'm going with #2.